# What are couplets called in Sanskrit?

Tags: sanskrit

I know that quatrains are called pAdas in Sanskrit. But what is the technical term for couplets in Sanskrit? I'm having lots of trouble identifying this.

Comment: I mean two pAdas. For instance, if you were to define a new pATa using just the first 2 lines of gana pATa, would you call each line a pAda or something else?

Comment: You could ask this on [Sanskrit Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/98070/sanskrit-language) for a better answer.

Comment: Quatrains are *not* called pādas. A pāda is a quarter (one-fourth) of a verse. (It is coincidence that it also means “foot” (not to be confused with what is called “foot” in English in the context of poetry); that's because most animals have four feet.)

Comment: This is off topic to Hinduism

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most common name in Sanskrit is śloka (श्लोक). A single śloka contains 2 lines of Sanskrit text, usually consisting of an equal amount of syllables. Lots of Sanskrit poetic works contain only a single meter for their śokas, but there are many kinds of meters and multiple can be used by a single work.

In order to understand the anatomy of a śloka, such as what is meant by pāda (or, ‘foot’), you can look at various pages on the internet, [such as wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shloka)

> The **śloka** is treated as a couplet. Each hemistich (half-verse) of 16 syllables, composed of two **pādas** of eight syllables, can take either a pathyā ("normal") form or one of several vipulā ("extended") forms.

The śloka form was developed from the [anuṣṭubh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anu%E1%B9%A3%E1%B9%ADubh), but you can find a more extensive list of meters [in this document.](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sloka-meter/files/Description%20of%20the%20Meters.%20PDF%20version.pdf/download)

Update: according to the [Nāṭyaśāstra 15.89-90](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-natyashastra/d/doc210082.html), an authorative work on prosody, a couplet is termed ''sampad'' (alternative spelling ''sampat''):

> “A **couplet** in which the number of syllables is neither in excess nor wanting is called a regular one (**sampat**).”

Comment: I believe the term shloka is misleading. Many sholaks are also written using pAdas, implying 4 lines. Yes, some are written in 2 lines. Thus, shloka is an umbrella term and by simply saying shloka, one wouldn't be able to extract that there are only 2 lines. For instance, a wide range of poetry, such as majority of Raghuvamsa and Vishnu SahasranAmam use anushtup chandas. But thank you for your answer!

Comment: I understand what you mean now. In Sanskrit prosody, the term pāda refers to both a quatrain (or stanza) and to a foot of the meter, referring to a repeating pattern of syllabels. I though you were referring to the latter.

Comment: Right. So, any terminology for couplets specifically?

Comment: Well, my best guess would be ardhapāda, literally translating to “half the fourth part” (Monier-Williams). But I will keep looking for official terms.

Comment: Another possible term could be dvipadī (https://www.academia.edu/6353023/Michael_Hahn_A_brief_introduction_into_the_Indian_metrical_system_for_the_use_of_students_) or dvipada, which literally translates to couplets: “The Dwipada is the easiest of all metres, being written, as the name imports, in couplets ; which generally rhyme together in prasa ; while other metres require four prasas.” (https://archive.org/details/AndhraGeervanaChhandamutheProsodyOfTeluguAndSanskrit)